# Flutter Error : [firebase_storage/unknown] location should not be a full URL

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to delete a file with a URL from FirebaseStorage and while deleting it I am receiving this error.

**Code**

```
Future<void> deleteImage(String imageUrl) async {
    
    try {
      await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(imageUrl).delete();
    } catch (e) { 
       debugPrint('Error : $e'); 
    }

}
```

I want to delete the image with given imageUrl. How can I achieve this..?

My imageUrl sample: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/flutter-8bd46.appspot.com/o/post_394be2ba-592c-45c9-9dab-fd72920f7afe.jpg?alt=media&token=98801435-192b-4ec1-b8e1-e73bac0bb9eb

Comment: Can you log and show what imageUrl look like?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Sure I have edited it in the problem.

Comment: You should pass only "post_394be2ba-592c-45c9-9dab-fd72920f7afe.jpg" in the .ref() can you try that?

Comment: Maybe `.refFromURL(imageUrl)` would work

Comment: @Dharmaraj
Thanks bro, Its Working..!!

Comment: Cool, I've posted an answer for the same. You can accept/upvote so others will know it's resolved else feel free to ask further queries ;)

Comment: @ShriHari Yes its working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you don't need to pass the domain or the complete URL. Only the path to that file is required. For example:

> /images/images.png

Alternatively you can use `refFromURL(url)` to use the URL instead of path.